# How to configure pytest in eclipse for single function

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pytest

In eclipse, i would like to know how to configure debug for single function.
I use pytest interpreter. 
In my file 'hello.py', i have several function

How to make this without using console:

> pytest hello.py::function

Comment: may be playing with arguments ??? or not possible with pytest.runner

Comment: use @pytest.mark.<test_name> and in your debug config put in arguments -m <test_name>